# Talkative and Outspoken Badges

Tags: support, badges

On our main site, UX.SE, to get the [Talkative](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/talkative) and [Outspoken](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/outspoken) badges, [Badges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges) just points to http://chat.stackexchange.com/.

Does that mean you can earn the badges by posting to ***any*** chat room on the SE chat network or does it need to be http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/ux-chat, our specific chat room?

If the latter, I'd like to report a bug, and have that chat link replaced with the proper one.

Comment: It's counter-intuitive to get badges for UX.stackexchange when you're talking about beer or sci-fi in a completely different forum. That being said, bug or not, I would recommend that the badges apply only to comments in the ux.se chatroom.

Comment: @Mayo - I agree. That's why I put the [tag:bug] tag on there just in case.

Comment: That was a good catch. I think the chat section would be a good resource if it was used more.

Comment: Maybe it's just a carry over from SE and all sites inherit it? In which case, maybe it _does_ work for all rooms? Who knows? That's why I asked.